# modelling data in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working on an angular application. I want to make an array at runtime. For this I need to define a model. My final array will look something like this.

```
data = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Location1",
      "subLocation": [
        {
          "id":2,
          "name": "subLocation1"
        },
        {
          "id":3,
          "name": "subLocation2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":45,
      "name": "Location2",
      "subLocation": [
        {
          "id":100,
          "name": "subLocation3"
        },
        {
          "id":200,
,          "name": "subLocation4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

So sublocation is an array which can have number of elements as shown above. For this what I tried is.

```
interface Location {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  subLocation?:  ?????????? //not sure how to do this so that when I call this model in my component I 
}                            can get a array like above
```

How can I do this so that I can get structure like above.

Answer (score 2):

You need a second interface for your sublocations which then get nested into the array. This way you can name and extend each level properly.

```
interface Sublocation {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
}


interface Location {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    subLocations?: Array<Sublocation>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as

```
interface WhateverYourSubTypeIsICanOnlyGuess {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  moreStuff: any;
}

interface Location {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  subLocation?: WhateverYourSubTypeIsICanOnlyGuess[];
} 

const loc: Location[] = [{
  id: 1,
  name: '1st',
  subLocation: [{
    id: 2,
    name: '2nd',
  }]
}];
```

Comment: Location and sublocation can have other different fields as well apart from id and name. how it will work in that case?

Comment: So I think subLocation can't be of type Location[]. Not sure though

Comment: No, it cannot. You'll get in trouble the further you get. Please, have a look at my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, then you define another type. You maybe could have be clear about this in your question...